# JSON to NSDictionary from http post request

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, nsdictionary, http-post

I created a simple php file to output a JSON String:

```
<?
$test = $_POST["hashcode"];
if ($ttest != "")
{
   $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'couponcode' => $test);
   echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

I am trying to use objective-C language to retrieve this json and parse it into a NSDictionary. I am currently using the JSON framework, but it isn't working for me.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse * response;
NSError * error;
NSString *post = @"hashcode=asdf1234fdsa";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.ski-inndronten.nl/json.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData *testJSON = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [testJSON JSONRepresentation];
NSLog(@"String = %@",jsonString);
NSDictionary *testDict = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"testDict = %@",testDict);
```

I hope you can help me out since I have no idea what I did wrong. (I am outputting NULL objects)

Comment: Just put some breakpoints. The response (testJSON data) does not have any value after the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there are two errors:

the first, you forgot to add "http://" in front of your URL string. If you don't do it the request will fail and returned data is nil.

the second, you are sending the incorrect application/json content type, if you do this the php will return an invalid answer. Simply remove this setting and the returned code will be correct.

By the way you can facilitate your debugging by logging the returned data as below:

```
NSData *testJSON = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:testJSON encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

If you do these two corrections, the answer will be correctly returned.

Comment: I posted the code on this website and wrote the variable $test as $ttest. If the json.php doesnt get a post request it doesn't output anything. I updated te code that it always outputs something. Unfortunately the NSLogs still ouput NULL representations.

Comment: see my corrected answer: issue found and code tested after corrections is working (I didn't test your JSON conversion because I don't use the JSON classes you have in your code, so I limited my check in controlling the POST returned string)